# Fatal error when i launch activity that contains fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

i call activity with this code above

this code below is my activity with fragment that add a preference xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/pippo3"
    android:name="com.example.-------------myapplication.MyPreferenceFragment$PrefsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
```

i return a fatal error

can you help me

thanks

Comment: Post the logcat here

Comment: use another root layout other than `<fragment> `

Comment: how another root layout?

Comment: i can open the tab only one time , if i retrying to click over tab IMPOSTAZIONI , the app crashes –

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_attendance, container, false);
    /*your elements*/

    return view;
  }
```

Comment: i can open the tab only one time , if i retrying to click over tab IMPOSTAZIONI , the app crashes